# Bar chart ggplot2 problems

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, statistics, data-analysis

I'm trying to run a bar chart using the ggplot2 function.
The way in which I want to organize the chart is as follows:
The "Larva" and "Pupa" appear on the X axis and the values referring to the 3 treatments in each of the "Larva" and "Pupa" categories on the Y axis.

Below is the example in which I want to reproduce however taking into account only the first two variables "larva" and "pupa".

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

gap3 <- aggregate(dados$nmol.de.H2O2.consumido.mg.de.PTNA ~ dados$Var2 + dados$Tratamento, data=dados, FUN=mean)

x11()
ggplot(gap3, aes(x = dados$Var2, y = dados$nmol.de.H2O2.consumido.mg.de.PTNA, fill = factor(dados$Tratamento))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack")
```

The following error appears:

```
Erro: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x, y and fill
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.  I changed the number variable name to `number` to make it easier to work with.

```
# load the data
dados <- structure(list(Tratamento = c("Controle", "Controle", "Controle", 
"Controle", "Controle", "Controle", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", 
"IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", 
"IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Comercial", 
"IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial", 
"IMD Comercial", "Controle", "Controle", "Controle", "Controle", 
"Controle", "Controle", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", 
"IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", 
"IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo", "IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial", 
"IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial", "IMD Comercial"), number = c(24477, 
33825, 24225, 15736, 21058, 21508, 23038, 28528, 38876, 35282, 
2466, 271, 18289, 15286, 23326, 18198, 19957, 22898, 9541, 12495, 
9672, 9723, 11265, 7627, 10617, 8553, 8483, 8071, 11029, 9408, 
10346, 13249, 9723, 11546, 9408, 9541), Var2 = c("Larva", "Larva", 
"Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", 
"Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", "Larva", 
"Larva", "Larva", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", 
"Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", 
"Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa", "Pupa")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# aggregate to get the mean
gap3 <- aggregate(number ~ Var2 + Tratamento, data=dados, FUN=mean)
# calculate proportions of the mean numbers
gap3 <- gap3 %>% 
  group_by(Var2) %>%
  mutate(prop = number/sum(number))

# Make the main plot
g1 <- ggplot(gap3, aes(x = Var2, y = number, fill = as.factor(Tratamento))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(fill="Tratamento", x="", 
       y="Number of Caste-biased Genes") + 
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1)) 

# make the inset plot
g2 <- ggplot(gap3, aes(x=Var2, y=prop, fill=as.factor(Tratamento))) + 
  geom_col(position="stack", show.legend=FALSE) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + 
  labs(x="", y="Proportion")

# put them together
g1 + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(g2), xmin=1.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=35000, ymax=60000)
```

[image]